# ListAdapter --> How apply convert view changes to specific view item only?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get have the lower part of list view slide down, by hiding an unhiding linear layout in list_item.  The problem is the view seems to get reused in LayoutAdapter so that the change does not just effect the view I intended to apply it to.  Instead it shows up wherever the view is reused. How can I restrict the drop down to just the view on which I requested the dropdown?  By drop down I mean unhide the linear layout.

Comment: I think you should check the View-Holder pattern.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up an array to track the state of each row (expanded or not),  and use that in the getView method of your adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will always be as many Views in the List as can be seen by the user. When the user scrolls, the views that go out of view get reused to show the new list data the user scrolled to. You need to reset the list item's state when they are redrawn.

Add a boolean variable 'expanded' to the object that stores the list data. (The objects you add to the ArrayAdapter). Set expanded = true when the user expands the LinearLayout in the listItem.

```
public class MyListItem
{
  public boolean expanded = false;

  // data you are trying to display to the user goes here
  // ...
}
```

Then do this in the list adapter's getView method

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListItem>
{
    public MyListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<AudioPlaylist> objects)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LinearLayout rowLayout;
        MyListItem item = this.getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            rowLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            rowLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }

        //set the textviews, etc that you need to display the data with
        //...

        LinearLayout expanded = rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.expanded_area_id);

        if (item.expanded)
        {
           //show the expanded area
           expanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
           //hide the area
           expanded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }           

        return rowLayout;
    }
}
```

Make sure your list_item.xml has a LinearLayout wrapping the whole thing otherwise you will get an cast exception.

Hope that helps...